# Controle 2 liferay portlets using a link

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay

I have two liferay portlets designed like this

```
---------------------  ---------
|                   |  |       |
|                   |  |       |
|                   |  |       |
|                   |  |       |
|                   |  |       |
|                   |  |       |
---------------------  ---------
```

I want to add a link using JSF primefaces in the portlet on the right side, if i click on it, this portlet is minimized, and it's space is taken by the portlet on the left side.

Any leads ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start from [Inter portlet Communication](https://www.liferay.com/c/wiki/find_page?pageResourcePrimKey=6629472)

I would suggest you use one portlet for this, and minimize using some of [JavaScript tools](http://speckyboy.com/2013/08/01/15-responsive-navigation-jquery-plugins/)
Also, check [primefaces tree nodes](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tree.jsf) and use ajax update to update the second panel.

As far as I know, there is no expanding and shrinking in portlets' world. if those portlets are tightly connected, you might want to consider merging them into one.

Comment: There actually is the concept of "minimize" and "maximize" for portlet states: "minimized" would show only the title, "maximized" would show only one portlet. However, I second the recommendation to consider having a single portlet if they're really tightly integrated. While the standard portlet behaviour would mean a roundtrip & page render, Ajax might be the recommendable way here - just expanding the "other" portlet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks devBinnooh for your answer,

Actually you'r right, it's preferable to use only one portlet because using 2 of them will create a lot of problems (such us communication which i beleive it's not an easy task).

Concerning primefaces i've used the component  p:layoutUnit with the property collapsible="true". and it works fine for me.